# How to validate promise (JS) syntax with ESlint?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, eslint

I am looking to validate the promise syntax, like this:

```
promise.foo(value).thedn((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  }).casch((value) => {
    console.log(value);

  });
```

if for example `then` is misspelled or `catch`. I am using Atom Text Editor, but I think that would be appliable for all editors.

Answer (score 0):

ESLint can't know that your `foo` function returns a promise, and can't know that a correctly-spelled `then` is necessarily a promise `then` (and so ensure that only `.then`, `.catch`, or `.finally` is used on its return) as opposed to something semantically different but sharing the same name.

If you want that kind of checking before runtime, you might look at [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org), which introduces a type system on top of JavaScript and validates at "compile" time from TypeScript to JavaScript (and on-the-fly in many editors [VS.Net, vscode, ... no idea about Atom]).

For example, in TypeScript you can define that `foo` returns a Promise of a string like this:

```
function foo() : Promise<String> {
    // ...
}
```

Then, this code would be flagged as an error by a TypeScript-aware editor and by the TypeScript-to-JavaScript compiler:

```
foo().thedn((value) => {
        console.log(value);
    }).casch((value) => {
        console.log(value);
    });
```

...because it knows that a Promise doesn't have a method called `thedn`. ([Live example in the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20foo()%20%3A%20Promise%3CString%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise%3CString%3E(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22done%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20800)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo().thedn((value)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D).casch((value)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B).)  And if you fix that, it will flag up the same problem with `.casch`. ([Live example updated](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20foo()%20%3A%20Promise%3CString%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise%3CString%3E(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22done%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20800)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo().then((value)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D).casch((value)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B).)